# Google Map js is not loading in Primeng P-dialog?

Tags: angular, google-maps, primeng

I created a map component and i written code for displaying google map but when I am trying to show  google map in p-dialog box in another component(by calling map component with selector),  its not displaying.

I am attaching stackblitz link for reference :-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-mzmmjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please help me in these issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your stackblitz Link! It works for me in the p-dialogue and when using the app selector in the main app. Both show the map! I am unable to reproduce your issue here:

https://primeng-dialog-demo-w5u2fx.stackblitz.io

Comment: Actually I continued the work in same stack blitz link and the issue was fixed, so its ran like without issues when u checked. Thanks for your time.